# How do I bind multiple dropdownlists

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I am dynamically loading a partial class with dropdownlists. The dropdownlists represent the many side of a one to many relationship. One person registering with multiple apartments. See pic below. Its all working up to this point. However, when I post back the form, I want the default model binder to collect all the selected values into the List in the viewmodel.

```
public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    public RegisterModel RegistrationData { get; set; }
    public List<OccupierApartment> OccupierApartment { get; set; }
    public SelectList ComplexesSelectList { get; set; }
    public SelectList OccupierTypeSelectList { get; set; }        
}
```

This is my question: What is the lambda syntax for the dropdownlists in the view: Something like this, but its only getting the first item in the list, whereas I need to get all the selected dropdownlists : @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OccupierApartment[0].OccupierTypeID, Model.OccupierTypeSelectList, "-- select --")

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you taking a look at the [following article](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) which illustrates a custom HTML helper which is adapted to this scenario of dynamically adding elements to a list.

Comment: Darin, I have had a look at that article before. The problem is that I am using dropdownlists and not textboxes. That is the essence of my question. How do I bind multiple selected values when using dropdownlists.

Comment: Another reason I dont want to use Ajax to post the page back (as per the link you posted) is that there is a redirect in the controller, which doesnt work when using an Ajax post.

Comment: No matter whether it is a textbox or a dropdownlist, it is the same principle. Both bind to a scalar property on your view model. The only additional step that you might need to take with dropdowns is to set the selected value.

Comment: But that is the issue - the property is not scalar, its a collection:List<OccupierApartment> OccupierApartment { get; set; }. I have tried looping over the dropdownlists in the view but I dont get back the dynamically added dropdownlists, although they are showing on the page.

Comment: But you have a scalar property inside this `OccupierApartment` class I guess. That's what you use to bind your dropdownlist for each row.

Comment: Yes, exactly - and that is my question. What is the binding syntax in the view for the helper (Its in a for loop). @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OccupierApartment[i].OccupierTypeID, Model.OccupierTypeSelectList, "-- select --") DOESNT bind all the dropdownlists. Aparently, the default modelbinder checks are the controls on the page, and if they have the same id, it will pass them into the model as a collection, but this is not happening in my case.

Comment: `m => m.OccupierApartment[i].OccupierTypeID` is the correct syntax. And if you want to preselect a value: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.OccupierApartment[i].OccupierTypeID, new SelectList(Model.OccupierTypeSelectList, "Value", "Text", ModelOccupierApartment[i].OccupierTypeID), "-- select --")`. But be careful because this won't work when you start adding and removing rows using javascript as it will break the indexing. The solution for this lies in the article I have linked to.

Comment: When I post back 2 OccupierApartment using the for loop, only the first one is bound to the viewmodel

Comment: Maybe you violated the standard convention: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx? Look at the generated source code and make sure that you respect it. Are you sure that the `i` variable that you used for indexing is incremented?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9531/discussion-between-greg-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: Greg, sorry I have to run. I have an important tennis match :-) You could mail me your code and I will take a look what's wrong with it later.